# Intializing a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to initialize a 2d arary in the following code  -

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[][5] = {
        [0][1] : 1, [0][0] : 2, [0][2] : 3,
    };
    cout<<a[0][0]<<" "<<a[0][1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler gives me following error -

```
./2d-arr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./2d-arr.cpp:7:4: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   [0][1] : 1, [0][0] : 2, [0][2] : 3,
    ^
./2d-arr.cpp: In lambda function:
./2d-arr.cpp:7:6: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘[’ token
   [0][1] : 1, [0][0] : 2, [0][2] : 3,
      ^
./2d-arr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./2d-arr.cpp:7:6: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘main()::<lambda()>’ and ‘int’)
./2d-arr.cpp:7:10: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘:’ token
   [0][1] : 1, [0][0] : 2, [0][2] : 3,
          ^
./2d-arr.cpp: At global scope:
./2d-arr.cpp:9:2: error: ‘cout’ does not name a type
  cout<<a[0][0]<<" "<<a[0][1]<<endl;
  ^~~~
./2d-arr.cpp:11:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
  return 0;
  ^~~~~~
./2d-arr.cpp:12:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
```

Whereas, if I replace ':' with '=' and compile it with gcc, it runs fine. My understanding so
far after googling the error message is that we can't initialize an array the same way we do in   C.
Is there anything that can be done to the code above to make it working for C++ ?

Comment: Since when does C allow `[0][1] : 1` ?

Comment: @TonyTannous since 1999 ;)

Comment: @Quentin this is why I like SO. You always learn something new. Though I've never seen an example... what should I search to find some?

Comment: @TonyTannous these are called designated initializers, however the `:` is a compiler extension -- the standard ones use `=`.

Comment: @Quentin I know [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) are supported in C99 and were introduced to C++ in C++20. The odd thing was the `:` which now I understand is a compiler extension.

Comment: @TonyTannous : For compiling with C, I changed it to '='.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code snapshot from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)
which states that the above initialization is invalid for C++.

```
struct A { int x, y; };
struct B { struct A a; };
struct A a = {.y = 1, .x = 2}; // valid C, invalid C++ (out of order)
**int arr[3] = {[1] = 5};        // valid C, invalid C++ (array)**
struct B b = {.a.x = 0};       // valid C, invalid C++ (nested)
struct A a = {.x = 1, 2};      // valid C, invalid C++ (mixed)
```

Its not possible do designated initializing using [] in C++ as it is in C.